# Get simple html text field to post to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

I feel dumb asking this question. I'm having a heck of a time trying to get a simple one text field in an html form to pass over to the MySql database via PHP. The id and date_time field are getting inserted but the text from the form text field isn't.

Here is what I got.

FORM.HTML:

```
<form action="php/comments.php" method="post" />
<input type="text" id="comment" />
<input type="submit" class="submit" value=" Submit Comment " />
</form>
```

COMMENTS.PHP:

```
<?php

mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO comments(comment, date_time) 
        VALUES('$comment',now())");

header ("location: form.html");
?>
```

COMMENTS TABLE (rows):

```
id
comment
date_time
```

Like I said the "id" which is set up as AUTO_INCREMENT and "date_time" rows are getting inserted. Comment, however, is coming up blank even though something was typed into the form.

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated. Can't quite figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: You are "missing" to enable register globals. Actually that's a good thing (even you think it might have broken something). Search the PHP manual for superglobal and $_POST.

Comment: add $comment = $_POST['comment']; before mysqli_query 
and add name="comment" to input element in form.html

Comment: You haven't given your comment field a name (as distinct from an ID). When you have named it your PHP script should see it as $_POST['whateverName'] which you can use in your query after you've suitable escaped it.

Comment: @hakre `Register Globals` was always dangerous, and has been removed in PHP 5.4

Comment: @MikeW: Register Globals was always a sign of how insane PHP could be under the hood and with the release of 5.4 I'm a bit more confident that the mad early years fade out a bit and this is getting more serious now :D

Comment: @user2079024 Please upvote any answers that are helpful to you, and choose a correct answer when done (to close the question).

Answer (score 3):

You need the `name="blahblah"` attribute when submitting forms.

On the PHP side, the name is how PHP receives the variable's "key" (var name) and then the field contents are the variable's value.

On the HTML side:

```
<input type="text" id="comment" name="myvarname" />
```

On the PHP side:

```
<?php

    $comment = $_POST['myvarname'];
```